# Moving from Influx to Postgres, need tips

Tags: postgresql, time-series, influxdb

I used Influx to store our time series data.  It's cool when it worked, then after about one month, it stopped working and I couldn't figure out why. (Similiar to this issue https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/1386)

Maybe Influx will be great one day, but for now I need to use something that's more stable.  I'm thinking about Postgres.  Our data comes from many sensors, each sensor has a sensor id.  So I'm thinking about structuring our data as this:

(pk), sensorId(string), time(timestamp), value(float)

Influx is built for time series data so it probably has some built in optimizations.  Do I need to do optimizations myself to make Postgres efficient?  More specifically, I have these questions:

1. Influx has has this notion of 'series' and it's cheap to create new series.  So I had a separate series for each sensor.  Should I create a separate Postgres table for each sensor?
2. How should I setup up indexes to make queries fast?  A typical query is: select all data for sensor123 for the last 3 days.
3. Should I use timestamp or integer for the time column?
4. How do I set a retention policy? E.g. delete data that's older than one week automatically.
5. Will Postgres scale horizontally? Can I setup ec2 clusters for data replication and load balancing?
6. Can I downsample in Postgres?  I have read in some articles that I can use date_trunc.  But it seems that I can't date_trunc it to a specific interval e.g. 25 seconds.
7. Any other caveats I missed?

Thanks in advance!

**Updates**
Storing the time column as big integer is faster than storing it as timestamp.  Am I doing something wrong?

**storing it as timestamp:**

```
postgres=# explain analyze select * from test where sensorid='sensor_0';

Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=3180.54..42349.98 rows=75352 width=25) (actual time=10.864..19.604 rows=51840 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((sensorid)::text = 'sensor_0'::text)
   Heap Blocks: exact=382
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on sensorindex  (cost=0.00..3161.70 rows=75352 width=0) (actual time=10.794..10.794 rows=51840 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((sensorid)::text = 'sensor_0'::text)
 Planning time: 0.118 ms
 Execution time: 22.984 ms

postgres=# explain analyze select * from test where sensorid='sensor_0' and addedtime > to_timestamp(1430939804);

 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=2258.04..43170.41 rows=50486 width=25) (actual time=22.375..27.412 rows=34833 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (((sensorid)::text = 'sensor_0'::text) AND (addedtime > '2015-05-06 15:16:44-04'::timestamp with time zone))
   Heap Blocks: exact=257
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on sensorindex  (cost=0.00..2245.42 rows=50486 width=0) (actual time=22.313..22.313 rows=34833 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (((sensorid)::text = 'sensor_0'::text) AND (addedtime > '2015-05-06 15:16:44-04'::timestamp with time zone))
 Planning time: 0.362 ms
 Execution time: 29.290 ms
```

**storing it as big integer:**

```
postgres=# explain analyze select * from test where sensorid='sensor_0';


 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=3620.92..42810.47 rows=85724 width=25) (actual time=12.450..19.615 rows=51840 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((sensorid)::text = 'sensor_0'::text)
   Heap Blocks: exact=382
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on sensorindex  (cost=0.00..3599.49 rows=85724 width=0) (actual time=12.359..12.359 rows=51840 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((sensorid)::text = 'sensor_0'::text)
 Planning time: 0.130 ms
 Execution time: 22.331 ms

postgres=# explain analyze select * from test where sensorid='sensor_0' and addedtime > 1430939804472;


 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=2346.57..43260.12 rows=52489 width=25) (actual time=10.113..14.780 rows=31839 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (((sensorid)::text = 'sensor_0'::text) AND (addedtime > 1430939804472::bigint))
   Heap Blocks: exact=235
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on sensorindex  (cost=0.00..2333.45 rows=52489 width=0) (actual time=10.059..10.059 rows=31839 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (((sensorid)::text = 'sensor_0'::text) AND (addedtime > 1430939804472::bigint))
 Planning time: 0.154 ms
 Execution time: 16.589 ms
```

Comment: Your question is **way too broad**, touching upon multiple issues, and not following SO practice of asking specific questions on programming problems, specifying what you have done yourself. I would suggest that you edit this post to ask something specific and post additional questions for additional issues on the appropriate forums (e.g. Q.5 belongs on dba.stackexchange).

Comment: 16ms vs. 29ms on only one run for each version is no proof that "*integer is faster than timestamp*". The (small) difference can well be caused by caching or other things going on in the system ( you should e.g. repeat the statements using `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`)

Comment: I repeated that statement multiple times and integer is always faster than timestamp.  However, if I don't do to_timestamp(1430939804) and instead convert it beforehand, then it's as fast as integer.  Maybe to_timestamp is called many times and not optimized?

Comment: Regarding #6, say you want intervals of 5 minutes, you can do following: 

`SELECT date_trunc('hour', time)  + date_part('hour', time)::int / 60 * interval '5 min'  as time_period, count(metric) FROM tablename GROUP BY 1`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create a table for each sensor. Instead you could add a field to your table that identifies what series it is in. You could also have another table that describes additional attributes about the series. If data points could belong to multiple series, then you'd need a different structure altogether.

For the query you described in q2, an index on your recorded_at column should work (time is a sql reserved keyword, so best avoid that as a name)

You should use TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE as your time data type.

Retention is up to you.

Postgres has various options for sharding/replication. That's a big topic.

Not sure I understand your objective for #6, but I'm sure you can figure something out.

Comment: Thanks Bill.  Do you see potential performance problems if I have hundreds of sensors sending data points to Postgres every 5 seconds?  (That's about 8 million points every day)  And what if I need to select one series from hundreds of series, each containing hundreds of thousands of points.  I'll run some tests, but I also value your opinion.

Comment: You might want to look into something like this. http://zaiste.net/2014/07/table_inheritance_and_partitioning_with_postgresql/ You could do your splitting time based. Then to delete old data, just drop the appropriate child tables. I think you'll find that Postgres will surprise you when it comes to performance though.

Comment: I ran a test with 100 sensors, each one adding 50k points, and performance is very reasonable.  The only part that is kind of slow is bulk inserting points to the db.  I created an index on (sensorId, recorded_at) and then used COPY to insert the points, and it took over 2 minutes to add all the points.  Is that normal?  Another thing is that storing recorded_at as a big integer is faster than storing it as a timestamp.  I have updated the original question with output from psql.